# JDBC and Connection Pools in Glassfish App Server

Tags: jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

I want to set up a connection pool and JDBC connection on EAR deployment so I do not have to set it up on each App Server I deploy to manually.  What do I need to do?  Is there an .xml file I can put this information into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a single GlassFish administration console to manage multiple application servers throughout your environment, those application servers can share a common configuration. If each deployed application server has its own administration console, you can write a script to call the CLI (asadmin) to create and configure the connection pools. Actually, you can use the CLI to configure a distributed deployment in the 1st use case, but you'll have to specify which configuration you are modifying. The CLI is good for automation.

Hopefully the following resources help:

- http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4341/abdjl?a=view
- http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=GlassFishV2Architecture
- http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4332/6nfq988or?a=expand (for asadmin CLI reference)
- http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4332/create-jdbc-connection-pool-1?a=view (see --target to specify the target in a multi-host deployment)

John Clingan, GlassFish Group Product Manager

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be so terse, but this may be what you are looking for http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4502/beaqi?a=view