# Glassfish JDBC: Do I have to use only jdbc/__default?

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish

I try to use Glassfish/MySQL. I have created JDBC resource and JDBC connection pool for MySQL.

But if I tried to put MySQL JDBC resource in jta-data-source, nothing works.

Then if I tried to modify jdbc/__default and change its connection pool from DerbyPool to MySQL, it works. My entity gets persists to the correct table.

So do I have to use jdbc/__default only as my JDBC resource for my app? How can I use the JDBC resource and JDBC connection pool I created in my app?

I really have hard time understanding how to use JDBC in Glassfish.

This is my first time to ask question in this forum. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you inject your DataSource via the @Resource annotation? If so, there are to properties there, name and mappedName. With mappedName you can refer to the JNDI name as defined in the admin console. With name, you need to map the container name to the application specific name in the deployment descriptors. I'm not sure, but IIRC Glassfish will inject the default DataSource if you get the name wrong.

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](http://netbeans.dzone.com/connection-pooling-glassfish-nb) for a step by step tutorial on how to create JDBC connection pools in Glassfish server. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/820-4335/gibzk/index.html) is the official documentation on how to do it. Or you can read [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572895/how-can-i-create-a-mysql-connection-pool-using-asadmin-tool-in-glassfish-server)  question. And another resource that you can use is [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530150/jdbc-and-connection-pools-in-glassfish-app-server) question.

Comment: The instruction works fine in GFv3, but GFv4 does have an issue described in the question.

Comment: wikisky unfortunately I stopped using GF when oracle made the announcement that there will be no more commercial support for it going forward. However I remember when trying this the first time on GF3 I ran into all sorts of difficulties. Review the glassfish logs when you attempt to create a JDBC connection pool and then debug the error from there. You will find a clue into what you are missing in the logs